# Change last bar colour of bar chart

Tags: javascript

I am using chart.js to create a chart. So far everything is fine.My aim is to give the last bar of a bar chart a different colour. I  have checked chart.js documentation but I didn't find any option to change bar colour dynamically.

Here's my current code:

```
var barChartData = { labels : livelabels, 
                     datasets : [ { fillColor : "#E76E42", 
                                    strokeColor : "#C7754C", 
                                    data : livedata, } ] }; 
function showBarChart() { 
    var ctx = document.getElementById("barChartCanvas").getContext("2d"); 
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData,options); 
}   

$('#barChart').appear( function(){  
    $(this).css({ opacity: 1 }); 
    setTimeout(showBarChart,300); 
    },{accX: 20, accY: -10},'easeInCubic');
```

Comment: which chart are you using, atleast provide a link

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart

Comment: How does your code look like now?

Comment: var barChartData = {
         labels : livelabels,
         datasets : [
             {
                 fillColor : "#E76E42",
                 
                 strokeColor : "#C7754C",
                 
                 data : livedata,
             }

         ]

     };
  function showBarChart(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("barChartCanvas").getContext("2d");
        
        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData,options);

    } $('#barChart').appear( function(){ $(this).css({ opacity: 1 }); setTimeout(showBarChart,300); },{accX: 20, accY: -10},'easeInCubic');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code can be used to color the bars.

```
 BarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].fillColor = "#c53938"; //bar 1
 BarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].strokeColor = "#c53938"; //bar 1
 BarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].highlightFill = "#c53938"; //bar 1
 BarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].highlightStroke = "#c53938"; //bar 1
```

You can have the bar number as you want.

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Comment: could you please provide this with one example or fiddle something